# font shorthand line-height not inheriting on child elements

Tags: css

I have this declaration

```
body {font: normal .625em/1.2em Arial, sans-serif;}
```

I would normally expect that any paragraph tags etc would inherit the line-height and adapt it to there specific size. For example

```
p {font-size: 2.0em}
```

should have a line-height of 24px assuming a base 16px browser font size * .625 = 10px * 2.0em = 20px 1.2em line height on 20px is 24.

Odd thing it appears to be rendering as just 1em

If i change the body declaration to

```
body {font: normal .625em/1.2 Arial, sans-serif;}
```

omitting the em unit it renders correctly. So I guess my problem is solved but I have never seen this before and am very confused as to why this is. Does anyone know the reason for it? Sorry I cant point to a site I am building locally.

Answer (score 2):

Eric Meyer wrote on the topic of "unitless line-height" several years ago:  http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/

Basically, if you include the unit, then the line-height is based off of the ancestor element's font-size and not the current element's font-size.

Answer (score 0):

When a property is inherited, the inherited value is the “[computed value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#computed-value)”. This means that if you declare a value of `1.2em` for `body`, then the `body` font size is multiplied by 1.2 and the result is the value that will be inherited by any child of `body` that does not have the property set on them. No matter what their own font sizes are.

For [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height), there is a special rule regarding the use of pure (unitless) numbers: “The used value of the property is this number multiplied by the element's font size. […] The computed value is the same as the specified value.” This means that when you specify the value as `1.2`, then you get the same line height for `body` (the “used value”) as you get by using `1.2em`, but the inherited value (“computed value”) is the pure number 1.2. And this means that it will get multiplied by each element’s own font size.

The morale is that `line-height` should normally be set using a pure number. Moreover, it is generally best to set it for all elements, avoiding all inheritance for it, e.g. `* { line-height: 1.3; }`. (By the way, 1.3 is generally better than 1.2 for Arial. StackOverflow uses a value corresponding to 1.3, with Arial as the primary font, and the line height is hardly excessive here. But this depends on factors like line length of course.)